# Context-free grammar for { [^n a ]^n + [^(n-1) a ]^(n-1) + ... + [a] |, n>= 1 }

Tags: grammar

I need help with building context-free grammar for the next language:

{ [<sup>n</sup> a<sup>1</sup> ]<sup>n</sup> +<sup>1</sup> [<sup>n-1</sup> a<sup>1</sup> ]<sup>n-1</sup> +<sup>1</sup> ... +<sup>1</sup> [<sup>1</sup> a<sup>1</sup> ]<sup>1</sup> | n>= 1 }

```
n can be any natural number.
```

So the language contains strings like:

```
(a)
((a))+(a)
(((a)))+((a))+(a)
... and so on.
```

I tried to build a grammar and stuck: it seems that we need to store information about amount of parentheses somehow.

My questions are next:

1. Is the language context-free at all?
2. If it is not how to prove it? But if the language is context-free after all then what productions can produce its strings?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not context-free, and you should be able to prove that easily using the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages). You really should ask this on http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context-free

Comment: rici, thank you for your answer. I will take a closer look at pumping lemma and if I will have problems proving that the language is not context-free I will certanly repost the question on cs.stackexchange.com.
I just needed a proof that I am on a right way. :)